# How to distribute my NodeJS code to users?

Tags: node.js, curl

I have built a static website generator with NodeJS and React. If my users want to use it, they have to have NodeJS installed on their machine. My question is what should I do so that my users could just `curl http://install.mywebsite.com` and get the compiled NodeJS and my code?

I have got this idea from MeteorJS. They allows users to just `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` and get Meteor and Node installed on their computers.

I have never done anything like this before. Any guidance would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: https://install.meteor.com/ is nothing but a page that contains shell script. You just need to write your own shell script and host it at install.mywebsite.com

Comment: I looked at the script before. What I don't understand is how they allow user to download the code? Of course, the sh script run on the computer and download the code from somewhere.

Comment: curl --progress-bar --fail "$TARBALL_URL" | tar -xzf - -C "$INSTALL_TMPDIR" -o
This is the line that actually downloads the Meteor distribution - the distribution is  a tarball.

Comment: Yea, I know. But I still don't understand the whole thing. Let me rephrase my question as I think it's not very clear. So, I have a bunch of codes (CLI, generator, etc) that have dependencies on other NPM packages and NodeJS. How should I make it into a tarball so that my users don't have to install NodeJS and NPM packages? and what if users already have NodeJS installed, how do I make sure that my code depend on the NodeJS in the tarball? I apologize for the vague question as I don't know what I should do/ask.

Comment: @endymion do your users need node installed for anything else? Because if you're distributing a single app, and don't need node for multiple apps then you can just bundle it as an executable with node bundled right in. This way you can ignore the issue of having to check what OS or flavor of OS they're using to figure out the best way to install node on that system. If you're distributing an opensource project, then I wouldn't really worry about it. If you want to do what meteor does then you've found yourself a pretty good example, you should probably examine the shell script.

Comment: Well you would have to provide several methods for each major OS type Windows, Linux, and OS X or simply whichever OS these users will be using.

Comment: @tsturzl My users probably don't need NodeJS for anything else as I'm targeting front-end developers. In that case, I should probably make an .exe file? Would [nexe](https://github.com/jaredallard/nexe) suffice?

Comment: @endymion I've used nexe in that past with success. I haven't used for windows platform, but it should support it.